# Get Product Options for each Product in the Catalog

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-attribute, custom-options, catalog, attribute-options

I am trying to build a script that outputs all the product options for each product in the catalog into a CSV file.

I have tried using the code on this page: http://www.atwix.com/magento/configurable-product-attributes/

For this code:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');  
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true) as $option) {
    echo $option['value'] . ' ' . $option['label'] . "\n";
}
```

I get no output, what-so-ever.

For this code:

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}
```

I get this error:

`Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getConfigurableAttributesAsArray() in /home/tws2/public_html/getopts.php on line 71`

Ive been unable to find anything else on the internet for getting at the product options of a product with PHP code.

**Can someone please explain to me how to use PHP to get at all the product options data for each product in the catalog, so I can output all this data into a CSV file.**

The purpose of this is to transfer the product options data over to an identical Magento server that has the same catalog, just missing the product options data. Once I have all the CSV file of product options I was going to make another script to write them into the identical Magento server. This is how Ive been advised to do this task in-house, if you have a better suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your question?

Comment: not a proper solution. i keep transferring over bits of data only to realize that ive missed something out... then i have to transfer that, only to realize ive missed out something again... ive been repeating this process over and over again. a complete solution to this problem would be great!

Answer (score 2):

No answer but another option. Use `Avs_FastSimpleImport` to update product data with the attribute values. In the `FastSimpleImport` settings you can define missing options should be created

Check out the module [here](http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/)

Answer (score 2):

Please note that this code you can apply only to the configurable product:

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}
```

So you can check is product configurable before go to this code:

```
if($product->isConfigurable()) {
    $productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
    $attributeOptions = array();
    foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
        foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
            $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
        }
    }
}
```